# Perforce: How to get a list of CL description

Tags: perforce

I was preparing a report based on the CL's submitted in perforce for a particular period(eg: from 1/11/2014 to 30/11/2014) .

Is there any way that I can get list of CL- descriptions of the CL's in an excel for that period?

I tried using "p4 changes" perforce command, but that gives me only the list of submitted changes. I want the CL descriptions.

Answer (score 2):

Specify the '-l' flag:

```
p4 changes -l //...@2014/01/11,@2014/11/30
```

From 'p4 help changes':

```
The -l flag displays the full text of the changelist
descriptions.

The -L flag displays the changelist descriptions, truncated to 250
characters if longer.
```

So if you don't want the complete changelist description, but only a short description, you can use -L instead of -l.

Comment: Updated the answer to clarify that '-l' includes the full changelist description.

Answer (score 0):

One minor correction. Since you want *submitted* changelists, use the -s flag:

```
p4 changes -l -s submitted //...@2014/01/11,@2014/11/30
```

So that you get changelists with the status of "submitted."